# Load GIF using glide version 4.2.0 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I'm trying to load GIF using glide 4.2.0 in kotlin. I loaded GIf and image using the previous version of glide. it was piece of cake. However, I was following [this link](http://sjudd.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html#getting-started) to use new glide. But I can't load GIf with it.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_gif_using_glide)
        val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayout)
        val imageView = ImageView(this)
        GlideApp.with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load("https://s3.amazonaws.com/appsdeveloperblog/micky.gif")
                .into(imageView)
        linearLayout.addView(imageView)
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to first call `linearLayout.addView(imageView)` and only after start loading gif with `Glide` ?

Comment: WOW! It's working like a charm.
But this didn't create a problem when loading an image. Can you please explain to me why this is happening with GIF?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but from brief checking of glide source code, it seems that it verify first visibility/validity of drawable before showing gif (c.f. `GifDrawble`), so view must be visible. This is not the case for images, because standard `BitampDrawble` is used.

Answer (score 2):

For Glide 4+

```
    Glide.with(this).asGif().load("http://www.dreamworks.com/trolls/assets/downloads/trailer2_branch-eyebrow412.gif").into(gifImageView)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of resizing the gif in glide 4?

Answer (score 1):

Change in your code `GlideApp` to `Glide` for above Glide 4 version.

For more information review on it : [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_gif_using_glide)
        val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linearLayout)
        val imageView = ImageView(this)
        Glide.with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load("https://s3.amazonaws.com/appsdeveloperblog/micky.gif")
                .into(imageView)
        linearLayout.addView(imageView)
}
```